# How to deletel last node from firebase database onClick listener?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm using a button to delete the last entry in my database.

But once I click it, all the data  from Firebase is removed, not only the last entry. I know I can use "limitToLast" but I can't figure how to use it properly. How can I do this?

```js
 button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Query query = databaseReference.child("uploads").limitToLast(1);
                query.getRef().removeValue();

            }
```

Here is my Firebase Data Structure:
[database structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/neT86.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firebase doesn't support delete queries, where you send a condition to the database to perform an operation on each node. The `query.getRef()` in fact returns the node on which you are running a query, so in effect you run:

```
databaseReference.child("uploads").removeValue();
```

And this explains why the entire `uploads` node gets deleted.

---

Instead, you'll have to:

1. Execute the query.
2. Pull the results into your application code.
3. Perform the operation on each result.

So in code:

```
Query query = databaseReference.child("uploads").limitToLast(1);
query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot results) {
        for (DataSnapshot snapshot: results.getChildren()) {
            snapshot.getRef().removeValue();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        throw databaseError.toException();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You code is working as expected.  It's definitely going to delete everything under "uploads".  The problem is that your query is not actually being executed.  You are just building the query without running it.  I suggest reviewing the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#listen_for_value_events) to learn how to run a query, then use the query results to determine which child to delete.  You will need to add a listener to the query in order to actually get its results.